# AWS Redshift Data API using wrong port for executeStatement

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I'm attempting to use AWS Lambda to execute a `COPY` statement with the Redshift Data API that comes with the AWS sdk.  Looks something like this:

```js
const { Id } = await redshiftData.executeStatement({
    ClusterIdentifier: clusterId,
    Sql: 'COPY ....',
    Database: 'db-name',
    DbUser: 'db-user',
    StatementName: `my-copy`
  }).promise()
```

When I use the returned `Id` to look up the query's outcome I get:

```
{
    "ClusterIdentifier": "redshift-cluster",
    "CreatedAt": "2021-01-13T04:02:33.504Z",
    "Duration": -1,
    "Error": "Connection to redshift-cluster.<id>.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:1143 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.",
    "Id": "2ddd8336-fc33-49ea-9e8d-c22340875bee",
    "QueryString": "COPY dev.event FROM 's3://s3-path' CREDENTIALS '' JSON 's3://jsonpaths.json' TRUNCATECOLUMNS TIMEFORMAT 'epochmillisecs' maxerror 100;",
    "RedshiftPid": 0,
    "RedshiftQueryId": -1,
    "ResultRows": -1,
    "ResultSize": -1,
    "Status": "FAILED",
    "UpdatedAt": "2021-01-13T04:02:34.246Z"
  }
```

This error is pretty strange - I don't understand when the connection was refused - the initial `executeStatement` appears to succeed, because Redshift has a record of the query I can lookup with `Id`. I don't understand where port 1143 comes from either: 1) the default port of Redshift is 5439, 2) my Redshift cluster is using 5439, and 3) AWS won't allow me to set a Redshift cluster port to 1143 (out of range).

Any tips or insight on this error would be welcome!